# Как запустить через map или foreach правильно валидацию дат? С общего мапа один ответ

Tags: reactjs

```
let roots = this.props.routes.map(it => {
            return {
                startCityId: it.city.code,
                endCityId: it.cityTo.code,
                countryId: it.cityTo.countryId,
                territory: it.city.name+it.cityTo.name,
                startDate: moment(it.minDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")+'T00:00:00.140Z',
                endDate: moment(it.endTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD")+'T00:00:00.140Z',
                dayCount: it.daysCount
            }
        });    
DocumentsApi.sendBusinessTripValidation(startDate, endDate).then(() => {
                DocumentsApi.sendBusinessTrip(data, selectedOrganization, responsibleEmployeeId, purpose, employmentKind, hr.code, adminChief.administrativeHeadPersonId,
                    functionalChief.functionalHeadPersonId, roots, responsibles, personInfo).then(response => {
                    this.setState({
                        fileId: response.fileId,
                        vacationId: response.vacationId
                    });
                }).then(() => {
                    this.afterDocumentSign();
                })
                    .catch(error => {
                        let errorMessage = null;

                        if (!isUndefined(error.response)) {
                            if (error.response.status === 400) {
                                return Global.showErrorMessage("Вы уже выбирали эти даты");
                            } else {
                                handleErrorResponse(error);
                            }
                        } else {
                            handleErrorResponse(error);
                        }
                    });
            })
                .catch(error => {
                    let errorMessage = null;

                    if (!isUndefined(error.response)) {
                        if (error.response.status === 400) {
                            return Global.showErrorMessage("Вы уже выбирали эти даты");
                        } else {
                            handleErrorResponse(error);
                        }
                    } else {
                        handleErrorResponse(error);
                    }
                });
```

В массиве routes много обьектов массива и нужно через foreach проверить каждую startdate и  endDate!
Как правильно сделать? просто форич? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, что в переменной `roots` уже находится коллекция объектов, имеющих следующие свойства:

```
{
    startCityId: UUID,
    endCityId: UUID,
    countryId: UUID,
    territory: string,
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    dayCount: Number
}
```

Создадим на основании исходной коллекции `roots` коллекцию запросов, которые мы хотим выполнить:

```
let requests = roots.map(
  root => DocumentsApi.sendBusinessTripValidation(root.startDate, root.endDate)
);
```

Насколько я понял из Вашего примера кода, то `DocumentsApi.sendBusinessTripValidation` как раз таки и возвращает объект [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). А значит мы на правильном пути, и теперь в переменной `requests` - коллекция запросов.

Теперь, используя метод [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) выполним все запросы, данный метод гарантирует нам, что код выполнится тогда, когда будут выполнены все обещания, переданные в виде перечисляемого аргумента, или отклонено любое из переданных обещаний.

```
Promise.all(requests)
  .then(responses => {
      responses.forEach(
        response => alert(`${response.status}`
      );
  })
);
```

Возвращаемый массив значений у `Promise.all` сохраняет порядок оригинального перечисляемого объекта, но не порядок выполнения обещаний. Если данный пункт важен для Вас, то остается простой подход с `foreach`, а также `async/await` для выполняемых запросов. Вообще, рекомендую немного переписать код и вынести часть кода, к примеру, в хелпер, дабы разгрузить код компонента.

Вообще, данная бизнес логика должна распологаться на стороне сервера (IMHO), на стороне клиента Вы должны просто подготовить коллекцию в качестве входного параметра и выполнять все проверки на стороне сервера, а ответ получить в упрощенном формате, где вероятно добавится поле `isValid`, а вторым параметром будет уникальный идентификатор переданного объекта коллекции. В случае с множественным изменением состояния, если коллекция будет большая и Вы постоянно будете получать ответы и менять состояние - будет происходить ререндер компонента и может появиться мерцание. Также, вероятно, будет понижена производительность приложения в силу большого количества запросов и постоянной перерисовки UI.

А еще, если у Вас на сервере имеется система защиты от DDoS атак, и к примеру используются токены авторизации (токен доступа, рефреш токен, время жизни и прочая лабуда из токенов...), то при большом количестве "практически" одновременных запросов Ваш токен может быть автоматически заблокирован и стать невалидным, причем рефреш токен также будет заблокирован и поможет только перелогин (ну это так, взгляд в будущее).

Продумывайте архитектуру приложения на шаг вперед, а лучше на два или три (чем больше - тем лучше). Чтобы, казалось бы, в простой ситуации не наступить на старые грабли.

Comment: в общем лучше сервис валидации изменю) на тот который массив примет)